# Running command in the background using tox

Tags: python-3.x, testing, tox

I am trying to implement an additional CI procedure for an existing opensource product and I stuck into a problem, I have no idea how to solve it.

Ther idea behind the procedure is next.

- Documentation generated by `mkdocs` and `mkdocs` reporting (and failing) if any warnings issued.
- `mkdocs` running with serve subcommand in the background (similar to running in back with `&` at the end) - this is creating webserver at http://127.0.0.1:8080 with documentation.
- my test/tool checking running server and documentation it's serving.

### Question

How can I keep mkdocs running in background using `tox`? I need to keep it working while my tool doing own tests.

### I have attempt already to do next things:

- to use bash and run a command as

```
bash -c 'mkdocs serve --theme readthedocs'
```

it's not failing, website not accessible.

- next command failing to run with

```
mkdocs serve --theme readthedocs 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

PS:

- https://www.mkdocs.org/ is a documentation generator.
- my tool is a simple content checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice the issue with mkdocs (**that server needs some time to start**). Working examples for this scenario is next one:

```
[testenv:docs]
basepython = python3
ignore_errors = True
whitelist_externals = sh
commands =
    ; -s abort the build on any warnings
    mkdocs build -s --clean --site-dir build/docs/html --theme readthedocs
    ; running mkdocs to serve documentation on 127.0.0.1:3001
    sh -c 'mkdocs serve --dev-addr 0.0.0.0:3001 --theme readthedocs 2>&1 > /dev/null &'
    ; checking liveness
    deadlinks http://127.0.0.1:3001/ -n10 -r3 --no-progress --fiff

deps =
     -r{toxinidir}/requirements_dev.txt
```